# I have error#404 when trying to get to the index

Tags: php, yii2

I have **SiteController.php**

```
    /**
     * Displays homepage.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $categories = IndexCategory::find()
            ->with('category')
            ->asArray(true)
            ->all();

        $categories = ArrayHelper::index($categories, 'position_id');

        $partners = Partner::find()
            ->orderBy('position ASC')
            ->all();

        $this->layout = 'index-layout';

        return $this->render('index', [
            'index_categories' => $categories,
            'partners'         => $partners,
        ]);
    }
```

and have view in **views/site/index.php**

Also have **urlManager**

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName'  => false,
            'rules'           => [
                '/catalog/search'                => '/catalog/search',
                '/catalog/<slug:[0-9a-zA-Z\-]+>' => '/catalog/product',
                '/catalog'                       => '/catalog/index',
                '/register/<id:[0-9]+>'          => '/auth/affiliate',
            ],
        ],
```

And when i go to site/index, i get error 404
I tried to paste to the urlManager this:

```
'/' => 'site/index/',
```

But it didn't help
I am new in yii2, so maybe there a simple solution

Answer (score 0):

You can omit `/` prefix.

Add `'<controller>/<action>' => '<controller>/<action>'` as a last rule, it will catch all standard action routes.

Comment: But I need it to be in '/'. This site successfully works on other domain, but when i make it on local and on other domain, homepage on '/' now with error #404

Comment: Hmm, ok, keep it then. Does the solution work?

Comment: no, I also tried 'site/index' => 'site/index'